# Convert micro character for ANSI, I need the unicode of μ

Tags: replace, unicode, character, windows-1252

I have a μ character in my mySQL database. I would like to replace it, with the following code:

```
UPDATE produkte.produktliste SET Kurzbeschreibung 
=REPLACE(REPLACE(Kurzbeschreibung, 'μ', ''), 'μ', '');
```

The code works, but I can't save the command to a script, because the μ char is not ANSI. I was having a similar problem in the past, and solved it with "char":

```
UPDATE produkte.produktliste SET Link  
= REPLACE(REPLACE(Link, CHAR(160), ''), CHAR(160), '');
```

But, which number (like 160) does μ have? I have tried many values (181, 924, 956) but nothing works. Does anyone have an idea, why my statement does not work?

the numbers represent the unicode value of the char.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then this is not a mysql problem, but a problem of whatever script interpreter you use. Please tag appropriately

Comment: Hi fancyPants, I think it is a mysql problem, because, the commands are all mysql commands...

I don't know, maybe you're right. I run in Windows CMD:
    set file= -e "source command.txt"
    "%mysqlpath%\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" %user% %server% %password% %file% So is this a CMD problem?

Comment: `The code works, but I can't save the command to a script, because the μ char is not ANSI` -> when the code works, it's not a MySQL problem, when you can't save the command to a script, the problem is with your script. Either this, or you seriously have to work on your wording.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my problem.

Comment: You need to know what code page you're using. This could be a problem, since the Cmd window and Windows editors often use different code pages. You can find the code page for the command window with the `CHCP` command. P.S. this has nothing to do with Unicode, if everything were Unicode we wouldn't have these kinds of problems.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer! when I run the command I receive "active codepage 850". Okay, I thought it have to do with Unicode...

Comment: You have a problem then, since `μ` doesn't exist in [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). What are you using to see that character?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have this char in my MySql DB... and I would like to run a .txt Script from cmd to replace this char (the statement on my problem description)